# Removing all Annotations from the gutter in react-ace editor

Tags: reactjs, react-ace

I'm using AceEditor in my react project but I don't want to show errors or warnings in the gutter. How can I do that? I tried one way as follows but it didn't worked.

```
<AceEditor
    readOnly
    value={code || ''}
    mode="javascript"
    name="UNIQUE_ID_OF_DIV"
    editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
    theme="github"
    showError={false}
    width='auto'
    height={height}
    annotations={null} />
```

Thank you.